# What does "Windows Authentication details" for a server mean?

Tags: windows-authentication

I'd like to find out what "Windows Authentication details" for a server means.

Is it something every server running a Microsoft OS has? Like something that can be checked at a specific location, say 'Computer properties'; or does the server need to have some specific software, say IIS to have the authentication details?

Comment: You need to give more context, are you able to provide a screenshot or advise where any of this information is coming from?

Comment: Someone was asking for Windows Authentication details - a manner of speech to ask for the login details for the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Windows Authentication details" is not an official Microsoft term. Usually when people are using it, they mean the username and password that are required to log onto a Windows OS. These are the 'details' needed to authenticate against a Windows OS, that's all.

Comment: Thank you for this. The login details was what was being referred to.